# Internet Explorer 8 table padding

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I made a simple table with only 1 cell that should span 100% width of body and 100% height of body. However the text in the cell should not cover the whole page from edge to edge, so I applied a padding left and right to the cell (not the table!).

This works perfectly in all browsers (even IE7 and IE6!!!) except IE8. In IE8 the text in the cell overflows the entire page, without showing a horizontal scrollbar.

[image]

[image]

Does anybody identify any issues or could give any clues?

```
<table id="supportMessage">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<p>Ihr Browser ist veraltet und wird vom Hersteller nicht mehr unterstützt. Die Umfrage kann daher nicht richtig dargestellt werden. Wir sind jedoch sehr an Ihrer wertvollen Meinung interessiert.</p>
<p>Bitte benutzen Sie einen modernen Browser, wie <u>Google Chrome</u> oder <u>Mozilla Firefox</u> oder wenden Sie sich bitte an denjenigen der Sie zu dieser Umfrage eingeladen hat und bitten Sie um Hilfe.</p>
<p>Herzlichen Dank!</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

If you need IE8 to test please find a version here: https://turbo.net/browsers

Comment: nope. unfortunately didnt fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You my friend are fighting with the IE Box Model and browser defaults. I would suggest adding these attributes to the < table > element

BORDER=0
CELLPADDING=0
CELLSPACING=0

And remove margins and padding from surrounding elements

html, body, table, tr, td { margin: 0; padding: 0 }

Comment: i thought about that, but sadly that showed no difference. what i dont get is why there is no scrollbar....